# error al importar función

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Por alguna razón en perfil.js solo puedo importar la función mostrarMensajeError, si lo intento con otra función dentro del archivo utilidades.js da error:

```js
//utilidades.js
'use strict';

function mostrarMensajeError(msg) {
  const cuadro = document.createElement('p');
  const parent = document.querySelector('.userForm');

  const mensajeAnterior = document.querySelector('.userForm__mensajeError');

  if (mensajeAnterior && mensajeAnterior.textContent === msg) {
    return;
  }

  if (mensajeAnterior) {
    mensajeAnterior.remove();
  }

  cuadro.classList.add('userForm__mensajeError');

  cuadro.textContent = msg;

  parent.append(cuadro);

  setTimeout(() => {
    cuadro.classList.add('userForm__mensajeError--fade');
  }, 4400);

  setTimeout(() => {
    cuadro.remove();
  }, 5000);
}

function comprobarSesion() {
  const data = localStorage.getItem('user');
  console.log(data);
  return 1;
}

export { comprobarSesion, mostrarMensajeError };
```

```js
//perfil.js
'use strict';

import { mostrarMensajeError, comprobarSesion } from './utilidades.js';

console.log(mostrarMensajeError);
console.log(comprobarSesion);
```

[image: error]

Comment: Este código funciona. ¿Será un problema de cache?

Comment: El código es completamente funcional, puedes ver si no se ha actualizado abriendo el archivo en la pestaña sources de las devtools del navegador